# How to draw circles in given places?

Tags: matlab, plot, drawing, matlab-figure, draw

I want to draw a circle marker at the top of each peak on the following plot:
[image: plot]

I achieve this with the following code:

```
data = mzcdfread('sample1.cdf');

[pks,locs,w,p] = findpeaks(data.ordinate_values)
plot(data.ordinate_values)
```

where

`locs` returns the `x` value at the top of each peak and `pks` returns the `y` value of each peak. A sample of `locs` and `pks` is given below:

```
pks =

  10×1 single column vector

    0.6649
    0.7314
    0.7536
    1.3797
    0.2394
    0.4322
    0.2090
    0.5402
    0.6797
    0.3059

locs =

        1199
        2399
        3599
        4799
        5999
        7199
        8399
        9599
       10799
       11999
```

This is what I tried to draw a circle marker at the top of each peak, but it does not work:

```
% r as radius
r = 0.2
ang=0:0.01:2*pi; 
xp=r*cos(ang);
yp=r*sin(ang);

plot(data.ordinate_values, locs+xp, pks+yp)
```

Comment: You should leave a comment under the answer, asking the person for further clarification. The answer will do what you want, but you’re not using it in the right way. I’m sure the answered can further clarify how to combine that code with yours. Look up `hold on` in the MATLAB documentation.

Comment: You also need to hide lines of second plot, e.g. `plot(locs, pks, 'o')`.

Comment: Cris Luengo is right, it's my fault for including a partial answer only. You should use `hold on` too. I am editing my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the conventional `plot()` built-in function of Matlab with the `'Marker'` option to draw the circles:

```
plot(locs, pks, 'Marker', 'o');
```

You can also set the size and color of the circle markers:

```
plot(locs,pks,...
    'Color', 'r',...
    'Marker', 'o',...
    'MarkerSize', 14);
```

This implies that the curve given by `data.ordinate_values` and the circles at each peak are plotted separately. Therefore, you need to use `hold on` between your two plot commands (or when you initialize the figure).

```
figure;
plot(data.ordinate_values);
hold on;
plot(locs,pks,...
    'Color', 'r',...
    'Marker', 'o',...
    'MarkerSize', 14);
```